# Are there any algorithms which conserves the energy for quantum harmonic oscillators simulation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, computational-physics, simulations

well I am trying to simulate the quantum harmonic oscillator. I have tried a few algorithms like using the Rk_4, etc. the energy is not conserved in that. are there any algorithms which will keep the energy constant for the harmonic oscillator simulation

Comment: Have you looked into velocity verlet or other symplectic integration methods?

Comment: yes, but the verlet algorithm conserves the norm up to about 4 digits after decimal.

Comment: and energy is conserved for about 4 digits decimal

Comment: If you are trying to simulate a quantum harmonic oscillator, why not just consider each eigenstate separately and then recombine into whatever superposition you are interested in?  This should conserve energy as the expectation of the energy should be set by how you weight the superposition.

Comment: I have a combination now i have to evolve it. even if i decompose it and evolve it the energy of those decomposed eigenstates wont be conserved

Answer (score 1):

You want an algorithm in which every time step is unitary. One sketch of such  an algorithm for the generic Schrödinger equation is given by approximating the time evolution operator for a time step as 
$$\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H\Delta t} \approx \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{i}\Delta t H}{1 + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{i}\Delta t H},$$
where $H$ is of course the Hamiltonian and $\Delta t$ your time step. You can directly check that the r.h.s. is unitary.